linux command to prefix a value for all lines in a file except for first line and lines starting with hash symbol
Given a file input.csv as shown below,
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,JOINING_DATE,SALARY
1,T Natarajan,22-APR-2024,6000000
2,Velmurugan,22-JUL-2024,2000000
3,Rowin,21-OCT-2024,5000000
#END_OF_FILE

how to prefix "E_" to all lines except for first line and lines starting with hash symbol (#). The expected output is,
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,JOINING_DATE,SALARY
E_1,T Natarajan,22-APR-2024,6000000
E_2,Velmurugan,22-JUL-2024,2000000
E_3,Rowin,21-OCT-2024,5000000
#END_OF_FILE

Tried this command sed -i -E '/^(#)/! s/^/E_/' input.csv but it's updating the 1st line as well.

You are doing nothing to exclude the first line.
You can combine two conditions with braces:
sed '/^#/!{;1!s/^/E_/;}' input.csv

or perhaps
sed '2,${;/^#/!s/^/E_/;}' input.csv

or you can turn around the logic to skip those lines;
sed '/^#/b;1b;s/^/E_/' input.csv

(The b command says "jump to this point in the script"; without a label, it jumps to the end, skipping the rest of the script for the current input line.)
I took out the -i option; put it back once you are satisfied that the results match your expectation.
Also, the parentheses were not contributing anything, so I removed them too. With that, the script no longer uses any ERE syntax, so I took out the -E option as well.
The semicolons next to the braces are optional in some dialects, but probably necessary in others.
If you want this in Awk instead, that should be easy.
awk 'FNR > 1 && !/^#/ { sub(/^/, "E_") } 1' file >newfile

Standard Awk does not have any option like the -i option in (non-standard) sed; but GNU Awk offers -i inplace

You could also use awk as a solution
awk 'NR > 1 && !/^#/ {$0 = "E_" $0} "true"' input.csv
Explanation:
NR > 1 means execute from the second line onwards
And "true" means display all lines.
!/^#/: This checks if the line does not start with a #. If the line starts with a hash, this condition will be false, and the prefix will not be added.

"true" will work just as well of course, but the common idiom is simply 1. But this fails to capture the requirement to only replace on lines which do not start with #

Indeed any nonempty string or 0 is considered true.

You might use awk to print the whole line if it is not the first row or if it starts with #.
Else you print the whole line prepended by E_
awk 'NR==1 || /^#/ {print; next} {print "E_" $0}' input.csv

Output
E_EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,JOINING_DATE,SALARY
E_1,T Natarajan,22-APR-2024,6000000
E_2,Velmurugan,22-JUL-2024,2000000
E_3,Rowin,21-OCT-2024,5000000
#END_OF_FILE


!NF skips empty lines, not the first line.

@tripleee Yes you are right, that should be !NR but I changed it to NR==0 to make it clearer.

That's still not correct; the first line has NR==1. But I updated my answer with an Awk solution now.

@tripleee Should be ok now, your awk with sub is also quite nice.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '1!s/^[^#]/E_&/' file

If it is not the first line and does not begin with a # character insert E_ at the front of the line.

Using any awk:
$ awk '{print (NR==1 || /^#/ ? "" : "E_") $0}' file
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,JOINING_DATE,SALARY
E_1,T Natarajan,22-APR-2024,6000000
E_2,Velmurugan,22-JUL-2024,2000000
E_3,Rowin,21-OCT-2024,5000000
#END_OF_FILE


I tried this with some other approach, However it works only with the lines provided.
sed -i -e 's/^/E_/' -e '1s/E_//' -e 's/E_#/#/' file


Adding something everywhere then removing it under some condition is always a worse (less clear and/or more fragile and/or less efficient) approach than only adding something under some condition. In this case if the first input line started with E_#7 then 's/^/E_/' would change it to E_E_#7 then '1s/E_//' would change it back to E_#7 and then 's/E_#/#/' would change it to #7 thereby corrupting it. You did say "However it works only with the lines provided." - obviously posting a script that only works with a specific set of input isn't useful.
